# Does creating multiple child objects also enforces creating mutliple parent objects in java?

Tags: java

In the following scenario

> ```
> public class Parent1 { }
>
> public class Child1 extends Parent1 {}
>
> Child1 c1 = new Child1();
> Child1 c2 = new Child1();
> ```

objects c1,c2 also creates two objects of Parent1 class?

and can you guys please tell me how can i check in real time ?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you create child objects, memory will be allocated for the members of parent object as well. You can check that parent object is being created by having a System.out.println in the parent class's constructor.

Answer (score 3):

It doesn't create a `Parent1`, but any fields in `Parent1` will also exist in `Child1`, so in terms of memory used, it's almost *like* it did, but it didn't.

Comment: If you're using inheritance properly, those *are* two `Parent`s.  You can use them anywhere that's expecting a `Parent`, and they're even (partially) constructed by `Parent`'s constructor.  They just happen to be instances of a *subclass* of `Parent`...which is much like having an Animal which just happens to be a Dog.

Comment: That's not necessarily using it properly though. There are use-cases for that behavior, but that's not to say it should always be used that way. Prime example: you don't always want to pass a `Collection<T>` into your methods - you often want to limit it to a `Set<T>` or `List<T>` because you require the behaviors of the subtypes.

Comment: Of course there are times when you'll want to specialize.  But if you want a `Set<T>` or a `List<T>`, then that's what you should be asking for.  Accepting a `Collection<T>` and then casting it to what you really wanted, is almost always the wrong thing to do.  But a List or Set *is-a* Collection, then everything that's true for a Collection should be true for a Set or List.

Answer (score 0):

A child object *is* a parent object, so yes, you have created two parent objects: `c1` and `c2`.

This is not Java-specific, it is the basis of object-oriented programming.